# Ставится ли запятая перед "даже"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Необходима ли запятая перед словом "даже"?

> Оказался на довольно людной(?) даже в вечернее время суток улице.

Comment: я бы поставил и перед "даже" и после "суток"

Comment: Я тоже так думаю, но не уверен с этим, интернет не дает однозначного ответа.

Comment: @prostorech чтобы дать ответ, пожалуйста, используйте подходящую для этого форму ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая **не требуется**, но если автор считает, что ***даже в вечернее время суток*** -  пояснение и выделяет оборот паузами, то обособление возможно как авторское:

*... оказался на довольно людной, даже в вечернее время суток, улице*.

Answer (score 1):

1) Частица **ДАЖЕ** употребляется для смыслового выделения слов и в общем случае **не требует постановки знаков препинания**. В то же время слово может относиться к определенной синтаксической конструкции, например к обособленному обороту, и тогда перед ДАЖЕ **может стоять запятая.**

2) .***..оказался на довольно людной,  даже в вечернее время,  улице.***

Слово **суток** лучше убрать (оно лишнее).

Наличие частицы ДАЖЕ придает обороту самостоятельность и увеличивает его объем, что способствует обособлению. В этом случае обособленный оборот приобретает уточняющее  значение.

Сравнить (без частицы ДАЖЕ): ...оказался на довольно людной **для вечернего времени**  улице.

**Вывод**

Таким образом, **выражать свое мнение** (есть пояснение/уточнение или нет) автор может **при выборе структуры предложения**. Если же выбор уже сделан, то знаки препинания **должны соответствовать построенному предложению и делаются по правилам с учетом интонации.** Согласно правилам, оборот в такой позиции в общем случае может обособляться или не обособляться. Что касается интонации, то обособление желательно, чему способствует частица ДАЖЕ в начале оборота.

**Приложение**

[http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=даже&all=x](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5&all=x)

ДАЖЕ. I. **частица.** Употр. для выделения и усиления слова или словосочетания, к которому относится. Такое д. выговорить страшно. Из себя могло вывести всё что угодно, д. пустяк. **II. союз**. (присоединяет чл. предл. или предл., вносящие добавления, уточнения с оттенком усил.). Читал много, д. испортил себе зрение. Ветер сильный, д. верхушки деревьев клонит. Только с ним молчала, д. не здоровалась.